# How to save file based on relative or virtual path when using plesk?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plesk

I have a program in asp.Net MVC. My server is plesk.

I save my files using this method:

```
public string SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
{
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + file.FileName;
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(filePath);
    return fileName;
}
```

and file saving is OK in test computer. But after uploading on server I get this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hostname.com\mysitename.com\Images\myFile.jpg'

What is wrong with my code? Should I use something different when using plesk?

Comment: It cannot find the path on your server. Copy the path in the error message and paste it in the explorer address bar on your server to see if the path is correct.

Comment: @Afsaneh Try to switch write/modify permissions as on screenshot below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then, most likely it is because your IIS user does not have write permission to write on that folder. Add full permission on the folder. The user must be something like: `Plesk IIS WP User`.

You can simply allow write/modify permission for subscription in Hosting Settings:

[image: ASP .NET Plesk permissions file]